# How to create a hardlink

Tags: c

So I am making a program that hardlinks two files and one should mimic another.
Unfortunately, when i echo something to void.txt it doesn't appear in e.txt.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* tlink = "e.txt";
const char* trapcontent = "XP0S3D";
const char* blahblah = "void.txt";
int ret;

void traplink() {
    int fd;
    fd = open(blahblah, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    write(fd, trapcontent, strlen(trapcontent));
    close(fd);
    ret = link(tlink, blahblah);
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("Success!\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    traplink();
    int fd;
    fd = open(tlink, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    write(fd, trapcontent, strlen(trapcontent));
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

**e.txt** exists and I want it to mimic **void.txt**.

Comment: Please take some time to read [a `link` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html). Are the order of your arguments correct? And if `link` fails you should probably print a message about that. As well as for any other system call you use, which might fail without you even noticing.

Comment: On another note, if you write the same contents to the file using its link, how can you check if it works or not? Try writing some *different* data to the file when using the link.

Comment: Sorry, why do you complicate things so much?  The call to the `link()` system call is as you are using in your code, so the problem (which you don't say what do you expect and what you get instead) can be a permissions or other kind.  You complicate things calling directly to many system calls to write info in the file.  Why just not create a file, `link()` it, and see in the filesystem what has happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to swap the arguments:

```
    ret = link(blahblah, tlink);
```

and the program now behaves as expected:

```
$ ls -i *.txt | cat
73402775 e.txt
73402775 void.txt
```

Especially for I/O operations you want to check return values.

Comment: Works exactly as i wanted! Thanks for help.